# Passing variables to mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following list of variables and I am trying to pass these to the sql UPDATE statement.

But the update statement is not working, I realised that the ID value is not detected by the sql statement.

How should I go about doing it?

The form:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" data-pagination="true">
                                    <form name="form1" method="post" action="processUpdateAccount.php">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Account</th>
                                            <th>Email Address</th>
                                            <th>Contact</th>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>Town</th>
                                            <th>Address</th>
                                            <th>Postal Code</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="gradeU">
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userName" type="text" id="userName" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['name']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userAccount" type="text" id="userAccount" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['account']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userEmail" type="text" id="userEmail" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['email']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userPhone" type="text" id="userPhone" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['phone']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userCountry" type="text" id="userCountry" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['country']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userTown" type="text" id="userTown" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['town']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userAddress" type="text" id="userAddress" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['address']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input name="userPostalCode" type="text" id="userPostalCode" value="<? echo $rowsUsers['postalCode']; ?>" required>
                                            </td>

                                            <!-- link to updateAccount.php and send value of ID -->
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">
                                            </td>

                                            <input name="userId" type="hidden" id="userId" value="<? echo $rows['Id'];?>">
                                            <input name="userPassword" type="hidden" id="userPassword" value="<? echo $rows['password'];?>"> 
                                            </form>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

processUpdateAccount.php

```
if (isset($_POST['userId']) > 0)
        {
            // query db
            $Id = $_POST['userId'];
            $name = $_POST['userName'];
            $account = $_POST['userAccount'];
            $email = $_POST['userEmail'];
            $phone = $_POST['userPhone'];
            $country = $_POST['userCountry'];
            $town = $_POST['userTown'];
            $address = $_POST['userAddress'];
            $postalCode = $_POST['userPostalCode'];
            $password = $_POST['userPassword'];

            $sql="UPDATE users SET email='$email', password='$password', account='$account', phone='$phone', country='$country', town='$town', address='$address', postalCode='$postalCode', name='$name' WHERE id='$Id'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='testing' WHERE Id='28'");

            if($result)
            {
                echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=manageAccounts.php?msg=1">';
            }
            else 
            {
                echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=updateAccount.php?Id=' . $Id .'&msg=2">';
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you share the form html?

Comment: The hidden input `userid` has a value ` $rows['Id']` and a hidden value for password `$rows['password']` yet the other fields use `$rowsUsers`. btw, WHY are you adding the user's password as a hidden value??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching everything else from `$rowsUsers` and id from `$rows` so that might be the very typo which keeps your id empty.

```
echo $rows['Id'];
```

Most probably is

```
echo $rowUsers['Id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO - it's much safer than the approach you're taking. [This page](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) is a good introduction. In particular look at the section on Prepared Statements. So in your case, after connecting to the database, you'd have something like:

```
$data = array('name'=>$name,'account'=>$account, [...] , 'id' => $id);
$sth = $db->("UPDATE users SET name = :name, account = :account WHERE id = :id");
$sth->execute($data);
```